# How to migrate data from the source table A to a partition table B?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

I have a source table A, and have create a partition table B whose data is base on A, and for now, I want to migrate data from A to B,　As I don't wanna use such sql because I have run them in development the result is slow...

```
insert into B select * from A where cycle_mth = to_date('20180131','yyyymmdd');
commit;
insert into B select * from B where cycle_mth = to_date('20180228','yyyymmdd');
commit;
.
.
.
```

Does anyone has other ideas,the Oracle version is 12C r1, and the source table has about 60 million data for 27 months (which means in above sql the insert is 27 times ), for each month is 1.6 million data.

and the key partition(range-list) sql is

```
 PARTITION BY RANGE ( CYCLE_MTH ) INTERVAL ( numtoyminterval(1,'MONTH') )
 SUBPARTITION BY LIST (TAX_TYPE)
   SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE 
      ( 
        SUBPARTITION LIM1 VALUES ('gg'),
        SUBPARTITION LIM2 VALUES ('aa'),
        SUBPARTITION LIM3 VALUES ('cc'),
        SUBPARTITION LIM4 VALUES ('ff'),
        SUBPARTITION LIM5 Values ('yy'),
        SUBPARTITION Lim6 Values ('ii'),
        SUBPARTITION LIM7 VALUES ('pp'),
        SUBPARTITION LIM8 VALUES ('ee'),
        SUBPARTITION LIM9 VALUES ('ww')
      )
```

Comment: Would't the partitioning take care of sorting out the data by itself? I mean wouldn't it be enough to run `insert into B select * from A`? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Plirkee ,As too much data migration when use insert sql month by month on production env, I am afraid that will lead server performance pressure. as I have test on development env , These insert sql runs unstably.

Comment: you want another way to move the data in order to increase the performance. you can do that in a loop with partitioned column as condition, or for the bulk insert add index  cycle_myth, or add parallele hint.

Comment: @Moudiz, use loop with cycle_mth and TAX_TYPE? 
actually like this?
insert into B select * from A where cycle_mth = to_date('20180131','yyyymmdd') and TAX_TYPE = 'gg';
commit;
insert into B select * from A where cycle_mth = to_date('20180131','yyyymmdd') and TAX_TYPE = 'aa';
commit;
insert into B select * from A where cycle_mth = to_date('20180131','yyyymmdd') and TAX_TYPE = 'cc';
commit;
insert into B select * from A where cycle_mth = to_date('20180131','yyyymmdd') and TAX_TYPE = 'ff';
commit;

Comment: @Tom Actually, I was wondering  about your month per month insert strategy - instead of all data at once ... except if  you want to insert smaller chunks of data for some reason.  Also, may be you should consider `append` and `no logging` [nologging_append](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nologging_append.htm)

Comment: @Plirkee ,Actually I really dont know whether need insert them all or by month,I think insert by month is just easily to monitor the log( ･᷄д･᷅ ) ,did you have any advise？ or just insert with no logging

Comment: You may consider "exchange partition"

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit ,thx wernfried ,will test

Comment: @Plirkee,   please help review whether it is ok using such sqlInsert into /*+ append parallel nologging */ target_table select /*+ parallel(e,5)*/ * From source_table e Where e.Cycle_Mth= To_Date('20160630','YYYYMMDD');
   commit;